# Hows Mozenda Screen Scraper coded?

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler, web-scraping

I want to know how is the Mozenda Screen Scraper coded?

http://www.mozenda.com/screen-scraper

I shows a browser where user can select the fields he wants to scrap and it creates a crawl script out of it.

The crawl script generation part is clear to me, I want to know does it record the user actions which the user is doing in the browser.

I want to do something similar using C#.

Comment: Unless it's open source we can't possibly tell, for certain, how their code works. I hate to do it but it really is as simple as Google'ing "C# web page scraper" and you'll find numerous examples of what you're looking for.

Comment: @mike, I know how to make a scraper in C#, my question was how they are recording the user actions. Please have a look at the video in the link I shared and you shall understand my question.

Comment: Ah, well again we can't possibly know specifically how they do it since it could be done many ways but looking at their video I would start by using a browser control, capture the form object and fields, design a model for storing actions, build an interface for specifying actions... etc. It's such a hugh question I don't think you're going to get a simple answer because it's not a simple question.

Comment: Yeah I know its something very complex, but I have no options other than do research and find how they are doing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they run something like iMacros on the backend. I even noticed the iMacros browser icon in some of their screenshots ;-)

If you want to code something like this yourself in C#, the **IE webbrowser control** is the best starting point!

Answer (score 2):

@yc08m, I can tell you for sure that they are not using iMacros.  It is all coded with their own proprietary code.

Comment: Could you shed some more light please?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an extremely outdated post, but they seem to rely heavily on XPath, so first things first you would need to load the page into an object that you can query.  I'd recommend using something like Html Agility pack to accomplish this.